# How can I modify my mesh with a C# script while the game is running

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I am trying to change my script continuously while the Unity game is running after I have entered play mode. I made a procedurally generated mesh and assigned a mesh collider, filter, and a renderer component to the script.

Now I want the mesh to change heights while the game is running. I figure this would be done in the `Update` function but I am not sure how I would implement it.

Here's what I got so far:

```
void Start() 
{ 
    mesh = new Mesh(); 
    MeshFilter filter = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>(); 
    MeshRenderer render = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>(); 
    GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh; 
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material = grassMat; 
    CreateShape(); 
    UpdateMesh(); 
} 

void UpdateMesh() 
{
    mesh.Clear(); 
    mesh.vertices = vertices; 
    mesh.triangles = triangles; 
    MeshCollider collider = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>(); 
    mesh.RecalculateNormals(); 
}
```

Comment: You could show us an attempt?  And why cant you just scale the object?

Comment: void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        MeshFilter filter = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        MeshRenderer render = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material = grassMat;
        CreateShape();
        UpdateMesh();
    }

Comment: That is my start function ^^^

Comment: void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        MeshCollider collider = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }

Comment: That is my update function ^

Comment: I also have a create shape function that sets the triangles and vertices for the mesh @AresCaelum

Comment: Put that in your question so it is readable.

Comment: and please explain how its not working, although I could imagine changiung a mesh say 600 times a second could be a bit intensive

Answer (score 0):

Since the example code is not really complete, i´ll point you to some common possible errors:

- void Update() is called every frame depending on your framerate, void FixedUpdate() is called every frame on a semi-fixed framerate. If you want something to happen every (fixed) frame, you should place your code in there. In your example you just named your method void UpdateMesh() which does not mean it´s getting called each frame: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html
- from you posted code it´s not clear, if there are changes happening in void UpdateMesh() at all. For example there is no code which changes positions of vertices.