# Unity C# script, continously change mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write a C# script for unity 3d. I want this script to continuously change my mesh that I have created. I can not figure out what I should do further. `

```
void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        MeshCollider collider = gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        // for loop can go here
        for (var i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            vertices[i] += normals[i] * Mathf.Sin(Time.time);
        }
        normals = mesh.normals;

    }`
```

This is my Update Mesh function.

Comment: Did you try to read the Unity documentation? Espeically e.g. [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html), [`InvokeRepeating`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html), [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) .... ?

Comment: isnt this exactly the same as your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104136/trying-to-change-my-mesh-with-c-sharp-script-while-game-is-running-unity ?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you should add a script component in your Unity project. 
you can watch how to add the script in https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html 
and then on, you can use **Update()** function in **UnityEngine class** for calling your own function.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        UpdateMesh()
    }
    void UpdateMesh()
    { 

        ...

    }
}
```